ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1
I am trying to calculate the cosine similarity between two columns in a dataframe. the code snippet for it is as follows :
def cal_cosine_similarity(row):
    vec1 = np.array(row['sup_vec'])
    vec2 = np.array(row['vector'])
    return cosine_similarity([vec1], [vec2])[0][0]
cross_join_df['cos_sim'] = cross_join_df.apply(cal_cosine_similarity,axis = 1)

This works fine most of the times but sometimes I am getting an error like :
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
   return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
 File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
 File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'cos_sim'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3576, in _set_item
   loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
   raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'cos_sim'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/prism/src/main.py", line 79, in <module>
   res = job.run()
 File "/opt/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 45, in run
   self.start()
 File "/opt/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 71, in start
   raise e
 File "/opt/prism/src/jobs/v2/SparkJob.py", line 68, in start
   self.execute(self.input_data, 1)
 File "/opt/prism/src/jobs/v2/DprmMappingInference.py", line 289, in execute
   cross_join_df['cos_sim'] = cross_join_df.apply(cal_cosine_similarity,axis = 1)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3044, in __setitem__
   self._set_item(key, value)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3121, in _set_item
   NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3579, in _set_item
   self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1198, in insert
   block = make_block(values=value, ndim=self.ndim, placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2744, in make_block
   return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2400, in __init__
   super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 130, in __init__
   raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1

I am not able to locate this error. Is this error due to some functionality of cosine similarity function?

You said that sometimes the code doesn't work, but not always. The most obvious reason is that cross_join_df somehow doesn't have the key 'cos_sim' and does not allow a new key as a mean to create a new entry. I'm not so sure what kind of object cross_join_df is, but generically you can use the following function to determine if there's a cos_sim entry:
def check_have_entry(object,key):
    if issubclass(object, dict):
        return key in object.keys()  # .keys() not really needed here, just for clarity
    elif isinstance(object, pandas.DataFrame):
        return key in object.index
    return False

However, if your dataframe is some other object, the above function will not work.
